# socket node.js express 404 error

Tags: node.js, socket.io

From a simple chat example at https://github.com/guille/chat-example/blob/master/index.js

For information, I'm not serving html file through following code, either the html is going to be embedded inside this iphone app or hosted somewhere. Question is how to connect the html to the nodejs environment where the sockets will be handled or is it a must that the html goes through the res.sendfile statement?

```
    app.get('/', function(req, res){
      res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });
```

html

```
<script src="js/api/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var socket = io();
    socket.emit('chat message', "hello world");
});
</script>
```

I'm getting a 404 error, attached screenshot
[image: 404 screenshot]

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using res.sendfile when it should be res.sendFile  (capital F)

Comment: oh man... this was posted 6 months back but thanks for the reply :) you've got the green check mark :)

Comment: Thanks.  If anyone else comes across this post, I was hunting down mysterious 404's in express, and discovered that my problem was inappropriate use of next() between my app.use() and app.get() declarations. Hope this helps somebody track their problem down!